# CalledFromWrongThreadException using Service IPC connection

Tags: android, service, thread-safety, ipc, aidl

I'm using the tutorial [here](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/) to develop a Service that is (right now) just running a `TimerTask` to do `System.out.println("tick")` every second. My code is exactly like the code on the site, aside from some name changes. Everything works (the Service runs, outputs "tick") if I don't try to pass a String from the Service to the Activity.

**What I'm trying to accomplish** is to get a TextView in the main Activity to be updated with a String received from the Service. I have an `append(String)` method working fine that will update the TextView with new text. So in my Service's `TimerTask` I've added `listener.handleMessage("tick")` and my Activity implements the listener functionality:

```
 public void handleMessage(String msg) throws RemoteException {
    append(msg);
 }
```

When I run the application, `System.out` shows a "tick", then a stacktrace with the `CalledFromWrongThreadException`, pointing to the `append()` method as the source of the problem.

I know there's a few questions about this Exception, but most of them concern `Thread` and `Handler` issues; I couldn't find anything about Services. Anyone know if this is possible?

## Solution

Extend Runnable:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private String msg;
    public MyRunnable(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public void run() {
        appendNewline(msg);
    }   
}
```

and replace the callback with a call to global Handler:

```
 public void handleMessage(String msg) throws RemoteException {
    handler.post(new MyRunnable(msg));
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates to the ui have to occur on the ui thread and not a background thread (like that of the timer). To update the ui, declare a member variable of type `Handler` and call the post method, passing a new runnable instance that can update your text view. This is a decent [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

Comment: Well then, I guess the other questions _did_ have to do with mine. Hopefully someone else will find this useful though :p